# Replacing the missing categorical values in a categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to insert missing values in a categorical column from the same categories present in the column, but I would like to insert them randomly.

```
Column1:  Column2:
yes          no
no           yes
?            no
yes          ?
no           ?
?            ?
```

I would like to insert randomly "yes" or "no" in these missing values. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `fillna` and `np.random.choice`:

```
import numpy as np
df.replace('?',np.nan, inplace=True) #if you need to do this
df = df.fillna(np.random.choice(['yes','no'])
```

Output:

```
  Column1: Column2:
0      yes       no
1       no      yes
2      yes       no
3      yes      yes
4       no      yes
5      yes      yes
```

Or, you don't need to replace those "?"

```
df.replace("?",np.random.choice(['yes','no']), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['yes', 'no', '?', 'yes', '?'], 'col2': ['?', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', '?']})    
df.applymap(lambda x: np.random.choice(['yes','no']) if x=='?' else x)
```

output:

```
col1    col2
yes     no
no      no
yes     yes
yes     yes
yes     no
```